# JQUERY, find closest id?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="containerA" class="container">
        <li>
        <span class="sportsType" id="football">Football</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="sportsMatch">
                <img src="/static/img/arrow_left.png" class="subArrow"/>A vs B <img src="/static/img/arrow_left.png" class="star"/>
                </li>
```

When you click the PNG with the class star I want to return the top most ul (containerA). I could use .parent.parent.parent etc but it also needs to work with another set of lists which isn't quite as complex:

```
 <ul id="containerB" class="container">
 <li class="sportsMatch">
<img src="/static/img/arrow_left.png" class="subArrow"/>A vs B <img src="/static/img/arrow_left.png" class="star"/>
</li>
```

Here's my jscript, what can I put in it to get the id of the closest container?

```
$(".star").click(function() {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the closest anscestor of the clicked element (`this` inside of the event handler). If you want the `id` of the container, you can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop), or access the DOM element directly and access the `id` property (as @sg3s points out in his comment):

```
$(".star").click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest(".container"),
        containerId = $container.attr("id");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/L7JyY/

Comment: And without the jQuery overhead. Just because its on the page doesn't mean you have to abuse it for every little thing. I'm not sure if the [0] is needed with closest though.

Comment: I wouldn't consider using `attr` when you already have a jQuery object "abusing it for every little thing." I also think using `attr` in this case is a bit more readable than directly accessing the DOM element inside the jQuery object. But to each his/her own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`closest` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the element, then use the `attr` method to get the id:

```
var ul = $(this).closest('.container');
var id = ul.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for the top-most, it wounds like there might be more than one object with with `class="container"` in the ancesotor hiearchy.  If that's the case, then you would do this:

```
$(".star").click(function() {
    var topContainer = $(this).parents(".container").last();
}
```

If you want the closest ancestor with `class="container"` (e.g. not the top-most, but the one that is closest to the click-on object) or there is only ever going to be one ancestor with `class="container"`, then you would do this which is slightly simpler:

```
$(".star").click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest(".container");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UL always has a class 'container' and if there are no other element with the same class in between the PNG and that  you can do this

```
$(".star").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.container')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will bring you the first ascending parent matching the selector :

```
$(".star").click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil(".container").parent();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/